# Do spam-only posting users get deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-accounts, spam, offensive

Often spammers, or drunk people who feel the need to post racist/sexist/otherwise offensive content come to the site and post something spammy or offensive.

The good folks of this community usually respond fairly fast by flagging the posts as offensive or spam, and they get deleted soon enough. (Two recent examples, for the 10k users amongst you: [spam](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555265/622) and [offensive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/554407/622) posts.)

But the users, usually unregistered, still remain active. True unregistered users are "harmless" in the sense that it's unlikely for them to come back, so often suspensions are of little to no point, but it does make me wonder:

> Why aren't users whose only post was destroyed using spam/offensive flags get automatically deleted?

And if there is no automatic purging mechanism for these sort of users, perhaps it's worth implementing one?

Comment: We delete them when we see them. In fact, both spambots you've mentioned are now already gone.

Comment: It would make moderating marginally easier, but the posts get deleted anyways with enough "offensive/spam"-flags, and then we simply follow up and destroy the accounts.

Comment: I recall a recent event when a registered user posted an offensive photo as their only post, which was soon deleted, and then the user was suspended rather than deleted.

Comment: I would personally hate there to be an automatic user-purging mechanism: destroying such users is one of the few things I do as a mod that brings me pleasure.

Comment: While on this topic, please edit the content of both posts Asaf mentioned, so they are not visible to 10K users. (The posts are locked, so I cannot do this myself.) -- I've also flagged the posts accordingly.

Comment: I don't really know how it works on the database level, but *deletion* sounds like a license to begin anew by creating another account. If a user's account is kept in the system, and subsequent posts turn out to be of the same nature, automatic post ban will likely be triggered. From what SE developers say, it sounds like the automatic ban is not as easy to get around by creating another account.

Comment: @user103254: The dev team has been working on a way to identify where spam is coming from and to (hopefully) stop it before it comes in.  As this depends on the moderators giving the system data, we have been told to destroy such accounts upon sight.

Comment: Is there some significance to the phrase (?) “Cadearia Cle Stactived Oceakenning Mandamornigh Aerod”? Or is it just nonsense? If it's nonsense, then why that particular nonsense?